# Algebra-Quadratics and Logarithms

Tags: algebra

If the two roots of the quadratic equation $x^2 - 6x + 1 = 0$ are $\log a$ and $\log b$.  What is the value of $\log(a, a b^2) + log(b, a^2 b)$?

Comment: This question has nothing whatsoever to do with the computer language *Mathematica* and hence should be closed.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this in Mathematica could be

```
ClearAll[a,b,x]
eq   = x^2-6 x+1==0;
sol  = x/.Solve[eq,x];
sol2 = Thread[{Log[a],Log[b]}==sol]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now solve for `a` and `b` and then evaluate the needed expressions

```
sol3 = First@Solve[sol2,{a,b}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
(Log[a, a b^2] + Log[b, a^2 b]) /. sol3
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If need to do this by hand, then the Math forum will be a better place to post this at.

Comment: The poser states nothing whatsoever to do with *Mathematica*, may not know a single function, and just wants us to do a homework problem.  This question should be closed and the poser learn what this site is about, and move to a more appropriate site (math.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1):

```
{a, b} = E^(x /. Solve[x^2 - 6 x + 1 == 0, x])

(* {E^(3 - 2 Sqrt[2]), E^(3 + 2 Sqrt[2])} *)

Log[a, a b^2] + Log[b, a^2 b] // FullSimplify

(* 70 *)
```

Comment: Nice short cut.

Comment: Thank you very much for the great answer! Bob Hanlon